# Probability of getting two students from last group? In group of 4.

Tags: probability, statistics, combinations

8 Students is divided into two groups of 4 (2 equally large groups).

What is the probability that you as a student get 2 of the students you had in your group before if you do the grouping again?

Example: 
We have 8 students, student 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 and 8
If we say day 1 the students gets divided into group A and group B.
Group A = 1, 2, 3, 4
Group B = 5, 6, 7, 8

What is the probability that student 1 in group A gets student 2 and 3 in 
hes/her group when new groups are made the next day? (There are still 4 students in each group).

Answer (score 0):

In simple words it means 3 students from any group get the same group after re arranging the groups(A or B).

we join 123 as 1 entity , which you want to be together after regrouping

group A : 123 4

group B:5 6 7 8

so after new grouping 123(3 members)  may have 4,5,6,7 or 8 as their new 4th group member.They get group A or B ,they will be together .So they will have 1 new member from remaining 5.so probability comes out to be 1/5 or 20%.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that "get $2$ of the students you had in your group" means **exactly** $2$.

Suppose you are $1$ and in the first grouping you are grouped in *some* group as $1234$

In the regrouping, *wherever you may be placed,* you want two from $2,3,4$ and one from $5,6,7,8$ against unrestricted placements of three from the other seven,

thus $Pr = \dfrac{\binom32\cdot\binom41}{\binom73} = \dfrac{12}{35}$